# Masonry algorithm for d3.js

Tags: d3.js, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

Is there a masonry type algorithm for d3.js? (a la isotope http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

As a related question (if that's not available), how would I go about doing it?  Specifically:  I know the enter/update/exit paradigm of d3, but it seems like it treats all the points independently of each other.  If I wanted to change the layout of the 2nd point, based on where I put the 1st point, how would I do that?

Comment: Have you looked at treemaps? http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html

Comment: I have...the problem with it is that implies hierarchy of data and it takes away the control of size of individual elements.

Comment: Only need a one level hierarchy and you can specify the size in the data, but controlling the layout might be more of a problem: http://enjalot.com/inlet/4127332/

Answer (score 2):

The matrix layout might be what you are looking for, you can see an example here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1009139
edit: just found a second example providing similar layout: http://bl.ocks.org/herrstucki/5684816

Answer (score 0):

Here is a masonry layout for d3:
https://github.com/shawnbot/masonic

The demo:
http://shawnbot.github.io/masonic